# starting emacs from the commandline and setting line wrap to 60 - howto?

Tags: start-up, email, command-line-arguments

I'm new with Emacs and come from Joe.

There I started editing mail from the command line by

```sh
joe -rmargin 60
```

because **I don't want to generally set the right margin to 60.**

I can't find a similar command-line option in Emacs.

Is there one somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "line wrap"? Are you talking about having the editor break up lines at a given column, or are you talking about how it displays text you're editing?

Comment: Hi, I want to have the file saved after editing broken up lines at column 60. I'm not interested in how the file is displayed.

Comment: You could try setting the variable per-buffer for your mode for editing emails, or for `text-mode`, so that filling is set only for editing text rather than code. If you want to have that specific setting for a given instance of Emacs, you might want to look into the `--eval` option.

Answer (score 1):

While emacs doesn't have this feature, you can evaluate elisp on startup:

```lisp
emacs --eval "(setq fill-column 60)"
```

This will set the value for the initial buffer, however you may want to apply this to a mode instead, read on....

---

If you only want this for a spesific mode, you an do:

```lisp
emacs --eval "(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook (lambda () (setq fill-column 60)))"
```

---

With emacs 27 you can draw this on startup too:

```lisp
emacs --eval "(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook (lambda () (setq fill-column 60) (display-fill-column-indicator-mode)))"
```

---

Although in this case you would typically do this in your init file,
not using the command line, eg:

```lisp
(add-hook 'mail-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq fill-column 60)
            (display-fill-column-indicator-mode)))
```

Comment: My Emacs is 26.1
emacs --eval "(setq fill-column 60)"
does not what is promised - I suppose I have to load some "elisp" feature? 
But in the first place I'm content to learn that there is no such option and I have to look for workarounds.

Comment: `fill-column` is automatically buffer-local, so the suggested approach is flawed.  I think the OP also wants `auto-fill-mode`?  Better to do this with a mode hook, I think (possibly `mail-mode-hook`).

Comment: Updated answer, to include a `mail-mode-hook`

Comment: Heh. I was more thinking that `--eval` was not needed, and they could just do this in their init file.